# How to train a simple neural network to implement median filter?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

Task: Given the random sequential number of {0,1,2,3,4}, train a neural network to find the position index of number "2". This network mimics the median filter which finds the index of the median number instead of the median number itself. For example, given the input [3,1,0,2,4], the output/label is "3" (or [0,0,0,1,0]).

I can construct a simple neural network manually by setting the kernel and bias weights to do the job. And it did the job perfectly. The keras code is as following:

```
val_len = 5

def GetModel():    
    inputs_img = keras.layers.Input(shape=(val_len, 1), name='rank')
    net = keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 1, activation='tanh', name='layer1', trainable=True, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(-5, 5), bias_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(-5, 5))(inputs_img)
    net = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.abs(x))(net)
    net = keras.layers.Conv1D(1, 1, activation='relu', name='layer2', trainable=True, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(-5, 5), bias_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(-5, 5))(net)
    net = keras.layers.Flatten()(net)
    net = keras.layers.Dense(units=val_len, name = 'mid_pos', activation='softmax', trainable=True, kernel_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(-5, 5), bias_initializer=keras.initializers.RandomUniform(-5, 5))(net)
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputs_img], outputs=[net])
    return model

model = GetModel()
# do 2 - x
model.get_layer('layer1').set_weights([np.array([[[-1]]], dtype=np.float32), np.array([2], dtype=np.float32)])
# do 1 - x
model.get_layer('layer2').set_weights([np.array([[[-1]]], dtype=np.float32), np.array([1], dtype=np.float32)])
# do 1-to-1 connection
model.get_layer('mid_pos').set_weights([np.array([[1,0,0,0,0],
                                              [0,1,0,0,0],
                                              [0,0,1,0,0],
                                              [0,0,0,1,0],
                                              [0,0,0,0,1]], dtype=np.float32),
                                    np.array([0,0,0,0,0], dtype=np.float32)])
```

However, this simple model can't learn weights from examples (I tried many optimizers). The best accuracy it can reach is 0.2 which is random selection from 5 categories. The model can start to learn "layer1" if we manually assign the weights of "layer2" and "mid_pos" layer.

My question is: 1. why this simple model fail to learn from example? 2. how to improve its learning ability? Thanks for your comments. (BTW, a generalized cnn is not a solution)

Comment: It seems your initializers are wildly big. Let the standard initializers instead.

Comment: Also, you're using relu with such a tiny dimensional data. The chance of getting all-zeros with it is great. (Although in this case you're using `abs` before it, making "relu" useless)

Comment: I made a correction, the Dense units=5 (my bad I typed wrong previously). And I use loss='categorical_crossentropy' for optimizers.
Do you mean the abs operation makes back propagation of gradients fail? I agree the "relu" in "layer2" is not that important, but the "abs" operation does not harm the "relu" to do its duty.
I can do some normalization to fit the data in 0~1, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Relu changes values lower than 0. There aren't any values lower than zero after abs.

Comment: The relu does not apply on the abs layer, it applies on layer2. And if layer2 has negative weights or bias, relu sure will do its job on the outputs. Of course for the assigned weights the relu is same as linear. Anyway the relu here does not cause the model "untrainable".

Comment: Oh, you're right. Temporary blindness got me here :p

Comment: But do consider the other comment about relu in my answer. It's certainly something a lot of people fall into.

Answer (score 2):

About the model:

- It seems your initializers are wildly big. Let the standard initializers instead.
- Also, you're using relu with such a tiny dimensional data. The chance of getting all-zeros with it is great.